# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split', ScikitLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, classification, threadpool

I am attempting to use a kNN classificaiton model using scikit learn. My X data are columns of values between 0 and 1, and my Y data is 5 different health categories. Here is the code I am attempting to run.

```
    HealthX = Health.drop(columns='Reported_Health')#Produces a dataframe of all the population-by-health proportions
    HealthY = Health['Reported_Health']#Produces a dataframe of all the reported healths

    HealthX_Train, HealthX_Test, HealthY_Train, HealthY_Test = train_test_split(HealthX, HealthY, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 413, stratify=HealthY) #split the data into training and testing data

    kNN_3U = KNeighborsClassifier(3, weights='uniform') #Declares a Uniform-weighted 3-NN machiene learning model
    kNN_3U = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('model', kNN_3U)]) #appends the model variable to include scalar data processing using a pipeline
    kNN_3U.fit(HealthX_Train, HealthY_Train) #Trains the machiene learning algorithm on the given training data

    kNN_3U_Ac_Train = accuracy_score(HealthY_Train, kNN_3U.predict(HealthX_Train)) #Calculates the micro-accuracy of the machiene learning model during the Training Phase
```

scikit-learn is updated to its latest version. My code is running on the Anaconda3 package. This error does not occur when I use a Decision Tree Classifier, leading me to suspect that there is an error in my kNN classification model.

After running the code, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_29052/877452642.py in <module>
      3 kNN_3U.fit(HealthX_Train, HealthY_Train) #Trains the machiene learning algorithm on the given training data
      4 
----> 5 kNN_3U_Ac_Train = accuracy_score(HealthY_Train, kNN_3U.predict(HealthX_Train)) #Calculates the micro-accuracy of the machiene learning model during the Training Phase
      6 kNN_3U_BAc_Train = balanced_accuracy_score(HalthY_Train, kNN_3U.predict(HealthX_Train)) #Calculates the macro-accuracy of the machiene learning model during the Training Phase
      7 kNN_3U_Ac_Test = accuracy_score(HealthY_Test, kNN_3U.predict(HealthX_Test)) #Calculates the micro-accuracy of the machiene learning model during the Testing Phase

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    506         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
    507             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
--> 508         return self.steps[-1][1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    509 
    510     @available_if(_final_estimator_has("fit_predict"))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_classification.py in predict(self, X)
    259             # In that case, we do not need the distances to perform
    260             # the weighting so we do not compute them.
--> 261             neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X, return_distance=False)
    262             neigh_dist = None
    263         else:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\_base.py in kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    820         )
    821         if use_pairwise_distances_reductions:
--> 822             results = ArgKmin.compute(
    823                 X=X,
    824                 Y=self._fit_X,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_dispatcher.py in compute(cls, X, Y, k, metric, chunk_size, metric_kwargs, strategy, return_distance)
    256         """
    257         if X.dtype == Y.dtype == np.float64:
--> 258             return ArgKmin64.compute(
    259                 X=X,
    260                 Y=Y,

sklearn\metrics\_pairwise_distances_reduction\_argkmin.pyx in sklearn.metrics._pairwise_distances_reduction._argkmin.ArgKmin64.compute()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py in threadpool_limits(limits, user_api)
     70         return controller.limit(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)
     71     else:
---> 72         return threadpoolctl.threadpool_limits(limits=limits, user_api=user_api)
     73 
     74 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, limits, user_api)
    169             self._check_params(limits, user_api)
    170 
--> 171         self._original_info = self._set_threadpool_limits()
    172 
    173     def __enter__(self):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _set_threadpool_limits(self)
    266             return None
    267 
--> 268         modules = _ThreadpoolInfo(prefixes=self._prefixes,
    269                                   user_api=self._user_api)
    270         for module in modules:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, user_api, prefixes, modules)
    338 
    339             self.modules = []
--> 340             self._load_modules()
    341             self._warn_if_incompatible_openmp()
    342         else:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _load_modules(self)
    371             self._find_modules_with_dyld()
    372         elif sys.platform == "win32":
--> 373             self._find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex()
    374         else:
    375             self._find_modules_with_dl_iterate_phdr()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _find_modules_with_enum_process_module_ex(self)
    483 
    484                 # Store the module if it is supported and selected
--> 485                 self._make_module_from_path(filepath)
    486         finally:
    487             kernel_32.CloseHandle(h_process)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in _make_module_from_path(self, filepath)
    513             if prefix in self.prefixes or user_api in self.user_api:
    514                 module_class = globals()[module_class]
--> 515                 module = module_class(filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    516                 self.modules.append(module)
    517 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in __init__(self, filepath, prefix, user_api, internal_api)
    604         self.internal_api = internal_api
    605         self._dynlib = ctypes.CDLL(filepath, mode=_RTLD_NOLOAD)
--> 606         self.version = self.get_version()
    607         self.num_threads = self.get_num_threads()
    608         self._get_extra_info()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\threadpoolctl.py in get_version(self)
    644                              lambda: None)
    645         get_config.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
--> 646         config = get_config().split()
    647         if config[0] == b"OpenBLAS":
    648             return config[1].decode("utf-8")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your code is running on the Anaconda3 package.
But the Python path in the error message you provided shows, you are running the default Python installed in your Windows.

Try activating the virtual environment, install the required packages, and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! My code is currently hosted on a Jupyter Notebook that's running on Anaconda3, I assumed that would mean the code was running on the Anaconda3 package? Is there a way I can ensure this code is running on Anaconda3?

Comment: You can use `which python3` to see the path. If it is in the Anaconda directory, you can ensure that.